# Is it possible to convert a PNG to Javascript an animate it?

Tags: javascript

I have a PNG image and I was thinking about using it as a page loader. Since it's not a gif, it's not animated and it's basically just a static png image. I wanted to know if it's possible to actually convert that image to Javascript(canvas maybe?) and animate it?

Comment: Why use javascript? Just a simple CSS animation will do.

Comment: Check out SVG it may help https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

Comment: [canvasElement.getContext('2d').drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) Of course, that depends what you mean by animate. You may just want to use CSS, or JavaScript or both.

Comment: "convert that image to Javascript" doesn't mean anything.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `animate` property and the `@keyframes` at-rule can be used to achieve this goal.  For example...

```css
body {
    background:#fff;
}

@keyframes arrow {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#loadingIMG {
    position: fixed;
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    margin: auto;

    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;

    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: arrow 1s ease-out infinite;

    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<img id="loadingIMG" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAQAAAAAYLlVAAAACXBIWXMAAAQKAAAECgFCV1GHAAAEOUlEQVRo3sWZXWhcRRTHf3c32Xy0u5svWhrSuC0FUyKlpASTUvogKIKCPipYMOJTP2xrjemT2laltA1UheJD/XgQfbCgFCtosGhQRNPvVmLS0KQg9aHJZjfZbLJJdscH3bDbnTv3zuzd9czb3HPn/58z58ycOWOhIz5CROhkMxvZQCOrqMUiyRz3mWCcW1zmLnEy7oe0XOuF2MLjdNNGIzU2WvNEGeEXBrhJHKE1OSV4K3v4nikyCBctQ5Qf2M16xfQCdPE0G50NYBGhl6ssuoLObSmu0UerdNQ6jvE3Ca7wrBo+xItcZkkbPNuWGKKHcAH8aVL/aQyp5r6Nc8wZg2dbki/Zmgf/3gq8IGUHX80LjBQNnm3D7KIagHrez4EXdo5axzvEPYMXCGK8SZA6PngAXkpgDR+y4Cm8QDDPR5wtgJcQWMtnLHsO/294pgt7KwqMf4Tn8DsEp2CGWeJMMomgngbqCRNy+M+SRX0+gSp66VEOkybKDQb5mXGSpFhEECBAFREepZsOWqjEWHYRU5rwNm/RSdh2/6phE4e4rrVz5Mg2ZeD9RT/t+BwnYRHhdYb1CYQ4Z6uU5lu6NExrsZXzLu2wIj0kbVSSnGGd9nKu4YRyQR8gEOGSjUKUPoJGHtXMRfcEem1iP0mfoVeHOcW8WwKtXLFZ+zOsNoTvd7mbArDHxmEu0FxieAEQ4jubwOsuObwA2MmU9FM/FQbwQU5pHWXAUemHUR4xgLc44Mr1cgjUMyDpznDEdcacK0224WzTfDxEm2SgSS5gklZnWNTSv+ejk0bJhxuMGMDDNJ+TcK09y9kKNkuvGYPEjQgIPmGK7QWZsEySDHIevpasTIzHjOCz4ifgovkBKtggNc14UQTSpN2q+qQeECdZFAEN8bFK0jtpf2HwnkCtlIBeMBVF4H8Wn3S1mwiUj8CclEBV+QhMSXrDUs8oEQFZxAelu0OJCNyRWmBH+QgMMy/p3+lqN/eEwJDUC7bwcLkI3OVPSX8TTxklJAYEpvlV0m/xPO3lIOAH0jwjyQkaWeCiTs3TXLxOy7UtkCLME5JTIcQ6fmS2SIQgT9LMPXWG4P3VLCu1HCfBffY7nS7eX04BKnmVBALBNK+oKZTiel7DQaIr4zhS8LpA0cAxZvLGmWafyppelmh8dPCVpCgZZa9qFK+KVOs5zJjtgr6k2mGLLdNV085hLinLUwP5x1z+UFW8wWtKVyksVGbwU8lqWulgB120KAudS7zL2yzbEYA6jvOyVql2iVrCtNBA0LGekOFj+oiqlUpZrP6CtY4+RKnK9Yt86r7i5P2DRYKTNLiFB6+fbCbYJ70CKsWrR6sU39BtegMr9tkuzR8cpMkMPGsH04fLZcY4yiYvMkvdp1vBDD9xiDbH/QSvH68XiDHMbwzyO1FcVdn0DCR7vocEc8SYYIxRrjFKTCeV/Qdc80zmGS9ZAwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

The image can be hidden or removed from view by adding a specific CSS `class` to the image...

```
/* CSS */
#loadingIMG.off {
    position:absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
}

/* JavaScript */
document.getElementById("loadingIMG").classList.add("off");
```

... or it can be removed from the browser with JavaScript in the usual way....

```
var LIMG = document.getElementById("loadingIMG");
LIMG.parentElement.removeChild(LIMG);
```

Hope that helps :)

- [CSS animation @ CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/)